# How to Serialize a JSON with an object key as id?

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson

How can I serialize an object with following format

> "level":{"3":"abc","1":"ddf"}

I am using GSON for serialization?

Comment: you can always use `JSONObject`.

Comment: Make a hashmap of key value pair to generate inner content ({"3":"abc","1":"ddf"})... and then at the end put that in JSONObject with key level ...

Comment: you can create custom deserializer (serializer)

Comment: @UmerFarooq yes,hashmap did the trick

Answer (score 1):

you can create class by this way and use @SerializedName(KEY)

```
 public static class Parent {

    Level level;

    public Level getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(Level level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public static class Level {
        @SerializedName("1")
        String valueOne;
        @SerializedName("2")
        String valuethree;

        public String getValueOne() {
            return valueOne;
        }

        public void setValueOne(String valueOne) {
            this.valueOne = valueOne;
        }

        public String getValuethree() {
            return valuethree;
        }

        public void setValuethree(String valuethree) {
            this.valuethree = valuethree;
        }
    }
}
```

and use

```
//initial
Gson gson = new Gson();
Parent parent = new Parent();
Parent.Level level = new Parent.Level();
//set value
level.setValueOne("abc");
level.setValuethree("ddf");
parent.setLevel(level);

//convert to String
String str = gson.toJson(parent);
Log.i("=============", str);
```

Comment: 1,2 are not static keys. That is dynamic, Hashmap <String,String>  works for my case,thanks for the help